# How to check in console selected nav?

Tags: angular, typescript

How to check the selected navigation by console.log

```
export const navItems: NavData[] = [
  {
    name: 'Book #1',
    url: '/book',
    icon: 'fa fa-book',
    children: [{
      name: 'Book #2',
      url: '/book',
      icon: 'fa fa-pencil'
    },{
      name: 'Shopping Plan',
      url: '/plan',
      icon: 'fa fa-shopping-cart',
    }]
  }
]
```

If I click Shopping Plan in sideNav, at console showing "Shopping Plan". Or if I click Book #2, at console showing "Book #2". 
In other words, how to console the selected navigation?

This is the HTML:

```
  <app-sidebar [fixed]="true" [display]="'lg'">
    <app-sidebar-nav [navItems]="navItems" [perfectScrollbar] [disabled]="sidebarMinimized"></app-sidebar-nav>
    <app-sidebar-minimizer></app-sidebar-minimizer>
  </app-sidebar>
```

Comment: add more explanation about the question!

Comment: @PrashantPimpaleis is it clear enough? or still need more explanation?

Comment: Show the `console.log()` code i.e how you console the value + HTML Code `(click)` event

Comment: If I am not wrong, you want to console the value of selected navigation --> Like if I clicked on `Book#2` then its should console the value as `Book#2`?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale right

Comment: @Show the HTML and TS code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make HTML like below (assign a `(click)`)

```
<app-sidebar-nav 
  [navItems]="navItems" 
  [perfectScrollbar] 
  [disabled]="sidebarMinimized"
  (click)="onItemClick($event)">
</app-sidebar-nav>
```

And add function in typescript

```
  onItemClick(e){
    console.log(e.srcElement.innerText);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is impossible to achieve this from the higher level component (in which the code you've shown is put).
The only way to achieve this is to modify the `app-sidebar-nav` and assign a `(click)` listener to the list items that are containing the `navItems`.
Meaning, in `app-sidebar-nav`, surely, you have got a structure like the following in html, add (click) to it :

```
<ul>
<li ngFor="let item of navItems" (click)="showInConsole(item.name)">{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

And in your component add :

```
showInConsole(name){
Console.log(name);}
```